Product Tags registering programmatically but return page 404 when viewing
I am developing a data synchronisation in wordpress from which I am retrieving the data from a 3rd party api.
The issue that I am facing is that the product tags are being adding programmatically however when I click on view named product_tag .../product_tag/test-tag it returns an page 404.
Product Tag
Weirdly enough, when I go on a product and add the product tag and look up the product tag that I want to add, the tag does not show up (those added programmatically via syncher). Those tags added manually via interface show up in the search.
I have tried:

batching the process
limit the process
added a product tag programmatically (on header.php)

try {
    $tag_name = ucwords(strtolower($product['product_sku']));
    $term = get_term_by('name', $tag_name, 'product_tag');

    if (!$term || is_wp_error($term)) {
        $term = (object) wp_insert_term($tag_name, 'product_tag');
    }

    if (!is_wp_error($term)) {
        $term_id = $term->term_id;
    }

    $add_product_tag = wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $term_id, 'product_tag', true);

} catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
}

I am logging step and it is showing that the data is being stored. I have looked into the database and the data is visible there.
So I am quite confused why it is not working when adding a product_tag programmatically within a syncer process.
Any help is appreciated!
Thank you
